# ¿Cómo validar en una tabla la presencia de un valor x?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Estoy aprendiendo de Selenium IDE. Hay algun comando que verifique un valor x en una tabla resultado de una busqueda filtrando por ese valor x?

La idea es revisar en esta tabla que el valor 64078 aparezca como Folio o como Monto(valor numerico). Hay comandos que ayuden en eso? Adjunto la imagen de la tabla.
Si alguien puede ayudarme.. Gracias de antemano!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

En Selenium IDE, puedes utilizar el siguiente enfoque para validar la presencia de un valor específico en una tabla:

Identifica el elemento de la tabla que contiene los resultados de búsqueda. Puede ser un  o cualquier otro elemento que contenga la estructura de la tabla.

Utiliza el comando "storeTable" para capturar los datos de la tabla en una variable. Puedes almacenarlos como una matriz (array) para facilitar su manipulación. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo se podría hacer esto:

```
storeTable | //table[@id='tabla-resultados'] | resultadosTabla
```

En este ejemplo, se asume que el atributo "id" de la tabla es "tabla-resultados" y se almacena la tabla en la variable "resultadosTabla".

Itera sobre los elementos de la tabla y verifica si el valor que buscas se encuentra en alguna de las columnas relevantes (Folio o Monto). Puedes utilizar un bucle "for" para recorrer las filas y columnas de la tabla, y el comando "storeText" para obtener el texto de cada celda. Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
${valorBuscado} = 64078
${tablaFilas} = getRowCount | ${resultadosTabla}

for | ${fila} | 1 | ${tablaFilas}
    storeText | xpath=//table[@id='tabla-resultados']/tbody/tr[${fila}]/td[2] | ${valorFolio}
    storeText | xpath=//table[@id='tabla-resultados']/tbody/tr[${fila}]/td[7] | ${valorMonto}
    
    if | (${valorFolio} == ${valorBuscado}) OR (${valorMonto} == ${valorBuscado})
        echo | El valor ${valorBuscado} está presente en la tabla.
        break
    end
end
```

En este ejemplo, se obtiene el valor de cada celda en la columna de "Folio" (td[2]) y en la columna de "Monto" (td[7]). Luego, se verifica si alguno de esos valores coincide con el valor buscado (${valorBuscado}). Si se encuentra una coincidencia, se muestra un mensaje y se sale del bucle.

Recuerda reemplazar "//table[@id='tabla-resultados']" con el selector XPath adecuado para tu tabla. También puedes ajustar el número de columna en los comandos "storeText" según la posición real de las columnas en tu tabla.

Espero que esta guía te sea útil para validar la presencia de un valor específico en una tabla utilizando Selenium IDE. ¡Buena suerte con tus pruebas!

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda Abraham.. Estoy comenzando con cursos de QA. Mil Gracias